# Shiro + Keys stored as strings = failure point or unnecessary concern?

Tags: mysql, shiro

Not getting into too many specifics, this is a high level question.

I've always gone by the idea that it is never a good idea to store primary keys in places that does not have a constraint. For example, storing a primary key in a EAV style architecture `("USER_ID",144)`. If that user is ever deleted it will not be reflected in the EAV mapping and cause issues farther down the road.

So I'm creating a new application using shiro as a `security/permission` framework and I need users to be able to edit themselves but not other users, I also need other users to be able to edit anyone. Simple enough:

`user1 = "user:441:edit"`

`user2 = "user:edit"`

In addition, I could have someone that can only edit a subset of users, something like this

`user3 = "user:459:edit","user:460:edit","user:461:edit"`

Or, someone that can edit users that are in a department but only that department

`user4 = "department:5898:user:edit"`

If someone from user3's list is deleted there's no way to update that user's permissions without magic (going through all the permissions and finding the ones to remove).

Now I don't plan to reset the keys but if it was to ever happen and I DON'T clean up the old keys I could have users suddenly being able to edit users who were recently created after reusing the old keys.

I could mitigate some of this by using a generated code `("user:ciS84nFSHK:edit")` that is unique across ALL TABLES to manage deletion of permissions. However, adding in a few hundred million records makes me think this can grow unwieldy quickly.

Am I using Shiro improperly? Am I simply overfocused on keys getting mangled? Have you solved these issues? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this sort of approach (nor do I use Shiro), but the case of ghost takeovers -- as pointed out -- only happens when an ID is re-used. So don't do that. A simple, slightly sledge-y, but quite effect method, is to just use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier). 32 hex characters, but a "well known" type and generally "as unique as most applications will ever care" properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research with Shrio I've decided to go with pst's suggestion and simply reference the values via a GUID (maybe a 10-digit-alphanumeric instead to preserve space).

So user1 = "user:441:edit" would become "user:96aae854-fc40-42ff-b948-c8944c2fca92:edit" this will help negate the concern about storing keys as strings.